# Play all playlists inside Playlist Folder with Apple Music app (iOS) as with iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, apple-music, playlist

In iTunes we can create a Playlist Folder (playlist folder) and include regular playlists to it:

[image]

Then we can play the entire folder (from the screenshot two playlists are played as one), but in Apple Music app for iOS we can only open that Playlist Folder and then play only a separate regular playlist, we can't play all playlists inside this Playlist Folder, it seems only possible with iTunes.